# Load javascript only when needed (on click)

Tags: javascript, ajax, load, lazy-loading, addthis

I am using the addthis widget on my site:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN --> 
<a class="addthis_button" href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&amp;username=abcdefg" rel="nofollow"> 
<img src="http://s7.addthis.com/static/btn/v2/lg-share-en.gif" width="188" height="24" alt="Bookmark and Share" style="border:0"/></a> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script> 
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Now, the javascript `addthis_widget.js`, is useful only when someone actually uses the share button.  How do I ensure that it doesn't load everytime, but only when someone clicks on the share button?

I am a noob in javascript, so some sample code will be much appreciated :)

### ADDED:

I wish to avoid using jquery or other libraries, because as you can imagine, I am trying to reduce the load time / number of requests / data on my pages.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is don't bother.

What you're asking for *is possible*, and there are a bunch of script loader tools out there, but that's not the point. The script there sets up the button so that it is clickable in the first place.

If you really wanted to only load the script if someone clicks on the button, then you'd have to:

- Add your own code first to detect a click, and stop the browser from redirecting to the default href
- Then load the script, which will cause a noticeable delay for the user
- Then invoke the correct behaviour on that script. I presume the script is external, and therefore probably isn't designed to work that way without some modification.

Sorry if this isn't the answer you're looking for, but unless that script is actually causing some delays, then really, don't bother :).

(You can, however, add that script to the end of your own JS file and load a single script at the end of your `<body>`).

Comment: Well said and nicely explained

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to generate the script tag when the use clicks the link and place in on the site. Can you use external libraries or frameworks such as jQuery to help you out?

Comment: Thanks, I wish to avoid jquery etc.

Comment: Well, as Box9 said — it's possible to do it, but he makes a pretty good point why 'not to do it'.